# Run Stored procedure in Azure SQL database from Excel and download results

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

When I connect to Azure SQL database from MS Excel, I do not see the option to see stored procedures, I can see only tables and view for a chosen database. How do I execute a stored procedures to download results to excel?

Thanks for your time and help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data-->Query to run the stored procedure in Azure SQL database from Excel.

Please follow my steps:
**New Query-->From Azure-->From Azure SQL database:**
[image]

SQL Server Database-->Advanced options-->Execute stored procedure statements:
[image]

**Click OK--?choose Database to connect to Azure SQL-->See the result of stored procedure.**
[image]

Then we can load the data into excel.

**Note: I use Microsoft Office 2016 version.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe Azure Synapse is essentially the same as SQL Server, with a few minor differences.  So, I'm not 100% sure that this will work, and I don't haccess to Azure now, but this will run a SPron sitting inside SQL Server.

```
Sub RunSProc()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "Data Source=Your_Server_Name;"
strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog=Your_Database_Name;"
strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

cn.Open strConn

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "MyOrders"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Text
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Text
Set rs = cmd.Execute()

If Not rs.EOF Then
    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A5:D500").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
End If

End Sub
```

If you want to make a request to SQL Server, and run any kind of SQL, you can do this.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '
     
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     
    Server_Name = "Your_Server_Name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "NORTHWND" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customers]" ' Enter your SQL here
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```